# Configure Jena to not report known issues

Tags: java, jena

Currently while converting in JSON-ld or turtle format I use Jena to convert the output into RDF/XMLjena Model. While doing that I do get several warnings.

Example

```
{"@timestamp":"2020-06-16T08:54:45.786Z","level":"WARN ","thread":"http-nio-8080-exec-2","class":"org.apache.jena.riot.system.ErrorHandlerFactory$ErrorLogger", "code_line_number":"95","message":"Lexical form '#2F4F4F' not valid for datatype XSD hexBinary "}
```

This is my code

```
InputStream targetStream = new FileInputStream(new File("ss_017407.rdf"));
Model modelResult = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel().read(targetStream, "", "RDF/XML");
```

For now, I configured in log4j to remove any warnings that we get from Jena. But I feel that is not a good solution. So I wanted to know if I can configure Jena to not report issues that we know already instead of completely removing them from logs.

I am using 3.13.0 version of org.apache.jena

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just suppress the logger for the parser warnings or if you want detailed control, you can provide your own error handler: see `RDFParser`:

https://jena.apache.org/documentation/io/rdf-input.html

With that you can decide which warnings to output.

Comment: Thank you so much. Helped me :)